# How can one class change another class value without the original class object

Tags: java, class

Please pardon me, I am trying to understand this concept, don't want to just accept it without knowing what is happening.
I read that only object of class X can modify itself, from the code below, Class 
ModifyX as a matter of fact can change X.x.num by calling it setNum method.

My questions are:

How come [`ModifyX` object "mx"] is able to change [ `X` object "x" ] value out of `X`?

The value of y passed as argument is changed in X, but why is it not changed in `main(String[] args)`?

```
public class X {
    private int num;
    public void setNum(int num) {
        this.num = num;
    }

    public void getNum() {
        System.out.println("X is " + num);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arsgs) {
        int y = 10;

        X x = new X();
        x.setNum(y);   //sets the value of num in X to y;
        x.getNum();   // print the value of num in X

        ModifyX mx = new ModifyX();     // A new class that is inteded to modify X
        mx.changeX(x);                 //calls the set method of X with new Value 5
        x.getNum();                // returns the new Value passed in changeX instead of y

        System.out.println("Integer Y is not changed = " + y); // but y still remains the same
    }
}

class ModifyX {
    public void changeX(X num) {
        num.setNum(5); // changes  y to 5
    }
}
```

Comment: You use a lot of delicate terminology in improper manner that's hints lack of understanding. I suggest you study some basics first to help yourself out.

Comment: Where did you read that? It's wrong. If a class has an accessible setter method or the field is accessible directly, then any object can modify that class's instances. As for your other question, where exactly is it changed in X?

Comment: I found you post ambigious. And what you get is what must happen. Be clear about what you want to know. For more help, see topics on `public methods access` and `Passing an object as argument to a method`.

Comment: @MohamedBathaoui the question may seem ambigious to you, because you have more knowledge about this than I do. Peter Lawrence pointed out "pass by value" which I had no idea about just like how you pointed that I should research more on passing object as args. Please don't assume everyone know as much as you do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method

```
s.setNum(y);
```

takes a *copy* of the value `y` and pass it to the method.  Java is always pass-by-value so it will always pass a shallow copy of the value.  This means you can change either copy of this value without effecting the other.

This method

```
num.setNum(5);
```

is the same as

```
num.num = 5;
```

so exactly one value is changed here which the the `num` fields of the `X num`.

Your local variable `y` is `10` and this variable isn't changed anywhere so there is no reason believe it should change.

Comment: @Nexima360 A common source of confusion is that `X num` is a reference and this reference is passed by value, but it is a shallow copy allowing you to change the `X` object which has been referenced. This means `x.num` can be changed but `x` cannot be changed for the caller.

Answer (score 0):

So 'num' is a non-public member of class X, so only the class itself is able to modify this directly. However, class X also provides the 'public' accessor function "setNum", which is a method which anyone using the class can use to "indirectly" set the value of the property 'num'.